How to do batch conversion of JPEG 2000 images to JPEG XL (lossless) while preserving the colour space of the image?
A long time ago I had converted some TIFF (uncompressed) images to JPEG 2000 (lossless) to save space. These JPEG 2000 images currently occupy some 20+ GB of space. Now that JPEG XL is here, and is a better archival picture format with many space saving features, I'd like to convert those JPEG 2000 images to JPEG XL with the following requirements:

The conversions should preferably be automated (batch conversion), and not require manual intervention.

The output JPEG XL images should be saved with the lossless option.

The output JPEG XL should have the same colourspace information (CMYK or RGB) or retain the same colour profile (if any) as the original JPEG2000 images.


What I have tried so far:

Old version of Photoshop - it doesn't support JPEG XL. Plug-ins for it are outdated with old JPEG XL reference encoders.
Latest version of GIMP - doesn't seem to even open CMYK files or automatically converts it to RGB; doesn't allow you to choose the JPEG XL options when saving a file in that format.

What other freely available software can I use to do this batch conversion? (I'd prefer software that can run on macOS Catalina but I am open to suggestions that run on other platforms too).

There's a website for JPEG XL which details what software supports it.  https://jpegxl.info/resources/supported-software.html  GIMP does support JPEG XL, but the Save dialog doesn't work for exporting, you'd need to use Export As to export a JPEG XL, but GIMP doesn't support CMYK.  Krita does though.  I can't answer the batch processing part of your question as it would probably require coding in GIMP/Krita. Sorry about that. If you don't want to spend any money, then maybe Darktable which is similar to Lightroom? I've never used it though.

I am checking them out. Apart from the CMYK issue, GIMP also doesn't give any options to choose the JPEG XL options (like lossless) on export. Krita for some reason is unable to read some of my JPEG2000 files as they use .jpx extension and also complains that it can't find any colourspace information in it (where as Photoshop has no issues at all). From what I could make out with DarkTable, it needs to import all the images to process it - that would be messy as all the JPEG2K files are in a different places buried within different folders and import-export to the right folders would be tricky

Disappointingly, as of September 2024, I find that there is still no real and proper support for the full features of JPEG XL in many of the graphic design applications or image converters.
Many fail to detect or use the original colour model or attached colour profiles of the input image and the output JPEG XL file is often silently converted to sRGB colour space. They also seem to fail to detect (or respect) the original DPI of the image and the output JPEG XL are 72 dpi (no idea if they are being downsampled or the DPI of the JPEG XL file is not being properly identified by the graphics application).
It is my opinion that JPEG XL is currently only suitable for use on websites and for photographs (perhaps in a limited manner).
